# Linearlayout changes size (ratio) when i set Image to ImageView

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I have a dialog with the XML code below, what i wanted to do is just like what is showed in first screenshot (and it is exactly what is showed on the screen when i keep the imageview empty) :

[Normal app running without image inside imageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUgRA.png)

but when i put the picture inside the imageView using the code :

```
ImageView img1 = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.imgView1);
img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.attention);
img1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```

the screen becomes :

[When app runs and image inside the imageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bn0Fo.png)

I dont want the linearlayout that contains the imageViews to change the ration, i put the weight ("3") to always keep same ratio, but although it changes.

above my XML source :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum ="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_field1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_field2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_field3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType = "fitXY" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType = "fitXY"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/imgView3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType = "fitXY"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/imgView4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType = "fitXY"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please any suggestion how to bypass this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure this is it, but try changing `android:layout_height` of the `LinearLayout`'s with weights to `0dp` instead of `wrap_content`. If it's not that, then it's still better since it doesn't need the extra calculations that `wrap_content` does.

(also, but unrelated: change `fill_parent` to `match_parent` in your code. It's newer and is what should be used nowadays)

Comment: Thank you very much @se_bastiaan. Your solution worked perfectly, i changed "android:layout_height" value to be 0dp.